# Integrating USB Camera on TI Hercules Evaluation Kit (ARM Cortex R4)

Tags: usb, arm

I am using a TI Hercules Evaluation Kit, which can act as a USB Host.

Here's the link  [http://www.ti.com/tool/tmdxrm48hdk]. It is a ARM Cortex R4 with 8 MB of SDRAM.

I want to use a Logitech Webcam (specifically the Logitech C200 Webcam). It is UVC compliant, so the UVC driver code for this can be found inside Linux source code.

I want some help on porting this driver code to my Evaluation Kit.

Is it feasible or am I aiming too high?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question. 
This was not feasible, because I wanted to capture 30 frames per second and for such high rates USB 2.0 is a must. My board does not support USB 2.0

Also there were not many sample USB driver codes available for this board.